# Data Not inserting in sqlite3 even after commiting in python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, web-applications

I am making a authentication web app , and trying to insert data in database and commiting it too but still doesn't work . I am using flask-sqlite,It says success but when I go my /list endpoint it is blank and even does't print's anything in console  . Here's the full code

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
import sqlite3  

app = Flask(__name__)
  
con = sqlite3.connect("details.db")  
print("Database opened successfully")  
  
con.execute("create table if not exists Users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL)")  
  
print("Table created successfully")  
  
con.close()  


@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    msg = "" 
    if request.method == "POST":  
        try:  
            email = request.form["email"]  
            password = request.form["password"]  
            print(name, email)
            with sqlite3.connect("details.db") as con:  
                cur = con.cursor()  
                cur.execute("INSERT into Users (email, password) values (%s, %s)",(email, password))  
                cur.commit()  
                msg = "User successfully Added"  
        except Exception as err:  
            con.rollback()  
            msg = "Sorry We Can't Signup You"  
        finally:  
            return render_template("res.html",msg = msg)  
            con.close()  

@app.route("/signup-page")
def signupTemplate():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/list")
def list_users():
    con = sqlite3.connect("details.db")
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from Users")

    row = cur.fetchall()

    email = ""
    password = ""
    for rows in row:
        email = rows["email"]
        password = rows["password"]
    con.close()

    return render_template("list.html", email=email,password=password)

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What error you are getting if any?

Comment: friend I am not getting any error, may I show you full code snippet , of all files?

Comment: if you are on github and there are no sensitive data, share it over there, and share the link, we get to see everything in a better perspective without cluttering in here. If however it is in a single file, then share the whole code above

Comment: Using f-strings to set values for insert statements is unsafe - use [parameter substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python) instead.

Comment: do you want html files also ?

Comment: I am having problems in making git repo

Comment: I had taken refrence of https://www.javatpoint.com/flask-sqlite#:~:text=CRUD%20Application%20in%20flask,contains%20information%20about%20the%20employees. and now problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this two lines.

```
cur.execute(f"INSERT into Users (email, password) values ('{email}', '{password}')")  
con.commit()
```

you can use format string in your query and `connection.commit()` not cursor.